# For Multi Language website should be go for sub domain for sub folder

Tags: subdomain, multilingual, language, multi-subdomains

we are planning to lunch business in multi-language. Now, the content will remain the same for all the website but, we are also trying to cater to the local audience. So, what will be the best solution for this should we go with subfolder or sub domain